# Using CASE WHEN statement instead of GROUP BY gives null

Tags: mysql, group-by, case, pivot-table

The query:

```sql
SELECT 
        R.GlobalMarket,
        G.AreaName,
        SUM(R.Revenue)
FROM REVENUE R
    INNER JOIN AREA A
    ON R.AnID = A.AnID
GROUP BY R.GlobalMarket, G.AreaName,
```

gives me correct results like:

```
GlobalMarket  Area      Revenue
BFS           NA Area   $20
BFS           UK Area   $10
Some more values..
```

I am trying to get Area-wise results as columns:

```
SELECT 
        R.GlobalMarket,
        CASE WHEN G.AreaName = 'NA Area' THEN SUM(R.Revenue) END AS 'NA Revenue',
        CASE WHEN G.AreaName = 'UK Area' THEN SUM(R.Revenue) END AS 'UK Revenue',
FROM REVENUE R
    INNER JOIN AREA A
    ON R.AnID = A.AnID
GROUP BY R.GlobalMarket
```

It gives me:

```
GlobalMarket  NA Revenue   UK Revenue
BFS           $20          null
Some more values..
```

Could anyone point out, why is so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the logic you use inside the `CASE` does not seem to be correct. I believe that if you try to run the same query in another database engine you'll probably get an error. I think that you must use the `CASE` statement inside the `SUM` and not the other way around. So turn this:

```
CASE WHEN G.AreaName = 'NA Area' THEN SUM(R.Revenue) END AS 'NA Revenue'
```

Into this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN G.AreaName = 'NA Area' THEN R.Revenue END) AS 'NA Revenue'
```

Please try it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I agree with your answer, I think your change will work better. I would like to add that in OP's query, both times he's using SUM(R.revenue) which has no restrictions it will likely sum the whole table. In your case, it is only summing the values that meet the given G.areaname.

Comment: jded, @McAdam indeed it helped..i was doing dumb mistake..thank you guys